# Need help with some stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC [Admin].[sp_Ques]    
(
 @QuesID bigint
 )
AS
BEGIN
 IF @QuesID = 0
  SET @QuesID =NULL
SELECT     FQ.QuesID, FQ.Ques,QuesAns 
FROM         Admin.Ques FQ

WHERE   FQ.QuesID = Coalesce(@QuesID,QuesID)

SELECT Language FROM Admin.Language WHERE LanguageID=FQ.LanguageID

END
```

In the second Select statement:

```
SELECT Language FROM Admin.Language WHERE LanguageID=FQ.LanguageID
```

In this statement, I want the value of "FQ.LanguageID" from 1st select statement, so I wrote this:-

```
LanguageID=FQ.LanguageID
```

Apparently didn't work.  It says "The multi-part identifier "FQ.LanguageID" could not be bound."

Do I need to pass this `LanguageID` to the stored procedure as a parameter and then use it as:-

```
SELECT Language FROM Admin.Language WHERE LanguageID=@LanguageID
```

How can I make this `LanguageID=FQ.LanguageID` work if I don't want to pass `LanguageID` as the second argument to the stored procedure?  Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps create a local variable to hold the LanguageID that's being retrieved. Assign a value to it during the previous `SELECT`. The addition of `TOP 1` simply ensures that if/when you ever have multiple matches in the first query (indeed you will when `@Ques` is zero or null!), only one value is returned in that query, thereby allowing a single value into your variable.

```
DECLARE @Lang int  --whatever datatype your QuesID is.

SELECT   TOP 1
           FQ.QuesID, FQ.Ques,QuesAns as QuesAns,
           FQ.QuesAns[Answers], FQT.QuesType ,
           FQ.QuesTypeID, FQ.QuesParentID, FQ.Active, FQ.AdminLanguageID
          ,@Lang = FQ.AdminLanguageID
FROM         Admin.Ques FQ
LEFT OUTER JOIN Admin.QuesTypes FQT ON FQT.QuesTypeID=FQ.QuesTypeID
WHERE   FQ.QuesID = Coalesce(@QuesID,QuesID)

SELECT TelerikLanguage FROM Admin.Language 
WHERE AdminLanguageID=@Lang
```

Comment: This doesn't work - you're both selecting and assigning to variable. Edit maybe? Don't want to downvote

Answer (score 2):

The scope of FQ is limited to the first select statement.

Your options include:

1. Passing AdminLanguageID as a parameter as you have suggested
2. Retrieving AdminLanguageID in a prior statement (select @AdminLanguageID = AdminLanguageID from...)
3. Joining Admin.Language with Admin.Ques
4. Using a subquery (select ... from Admin.Language where AdminLanguageID in (select AdminLanguageID from Admin.Ques where ...)

Comment: Move "DECLARE @Lang int" below the begin and give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just join them into 1 select?

```
ALTER PROC [Admin].[sp_Ques]    
(
 @QuesID bigint
 )
AS
BEGIN
 IF @QuesID = 0
  SET @QuesID =NULL
SELECT     FQ.QuesID, FQ.Ques,QuesAns as QuesAns,FQ.QuesAns[Answers], FQT.QuesType ,FQ.QuesTypeID, FQ.QuesParentID, FQ.Active,FQ.AdminLanguageID, AL.TelerikLanguage
FROM         Admin.Ques FQ
LEFT OUTER JOIN Admin.QuesTypes FQT ON FQT.QuesTypeID=FQ.QuesTypeID
    LEFT JOIN Admin.Language AL ON AL.AdminLanguageID=FQ.AdminLanguageID
WHERE   FQ.QuesID = QuesID OR @QuesID IS NULL

END
```