# need help with some stored procedure error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [need help with some stored procedure plz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352383/need-help-with-some-stored-procedure-plz)

ERROR:-

A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is that your select is updating a variable while spitting out the results at the same time.
Split up your queries as follows:

```
 ALTER PROC [Admin].[sp_Ques]    
    (
        @QuesID bigint
     )

    AS
    BEGIN
DECLARE @Lang int   -- ERROR HERE

        IF @QuesID = 0
            SET @QuesID =NULL
    SELECT TOP 1 @Lang=FQ.AdminLanguageID
    FROM         Admin.Ques FQ
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Admin.QuesTypes FQT ON FQT.QuesTypeID=FQ.QuesTypeID
    WHERE   FQ.QuesID = Coalesce(@QuesID,QuesID)

    SELECT TOP 1 FQ.QuesID, FQ.Ques,QuesAns as QuesAns,FQ.QuesAns[Answers], FQT.QuesType ,FQ.QuesTypeID, FQ.QuesParentID, FQ.Active,FQ.AdminLanguageID
    FROM         Admin.Ques FQ
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Admin.QuesTypes FQT ON FQT.QuesTypeID=FQ.QuesTypeID
    WHERE   FQ.QuesID = Coalesce(@QuesID,QuesID)

    SELECT TelerikLanguage FROM Admin.Language 
    WHERE AdminLanguageID=@Lang 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SELECT TOP 1 FQ.QuesID, FQ.Ques,QuesAns as QuesAns,FQ.QuesAns[Answers], FQT.QuesType ,FQ.QuesTypeID, FQ.QuesParentID, FQ.Active,FQ.AdminLanguageID,@Lang=FQ.AdminLanguageID 
    FROM         Admin.Ques FQ 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Admin.QuesTypes FQT ON FQT.QuesTypeID=FQ.QuesTypeID 
    WHERE   FQ.QuesID = Coalesce(@QuesID,QuesID)
```

To

```
SELECT TOP 1 @Lang=FQ.AdminLanguageID 
    FROM         Admin.Ques FQ 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Admin.QuesTypes FQT ON FQT.QuesTypeID=FQ.QuesTypeID 
    WHERE   FQ.QuesID = Coalesce(@QuesID,QuesID)
```

When you are assigning values to variables from a select, all items in the select list must be assigning values to variables. Not just some of them.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear - you cannot combine variable assignment and normal result set retrieval in the same query.

```
SELECT TOP 1 FQ.QuesID, 
FQ.Ques,
QuesAns as QuesAns,
FQ.QuesAns[Answers], 
FQT.QuesType ,
FQ.QuesTypeID, 
FQ.QuesParentID, 
FQ.Active,
FQ.AdminLanguageID,
@Lang=FQ.AdminLanguageID <---- this is the problem
```

Split the query and everything should be ok.